# JavaScript user input outside Browser

Tags: javascript

how can I get user input outside the browser in JavaScript?
I mean, in Python there's a input function to get information from a user. Similar to that, is there any function or something like that to get information from a user in JavaScript?

Comment: I think you should use node.js, look here (first site I've found): https://www.codecademy.com/articles/getting-user-input-in-node-js

Comment: [official site](https://nodejs.org/en/) of Node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **Prompt**

You could do something like this:

```
<script>

    let userName = prompt('Please enter you name:');

    console.log(userName);

</script>
```